# Error: near "DISTINCT": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I cant seem to figure out what is going wrong. I tried sub-parts of the query but still couldn't solve the problem.

Table Format:

```
poi(id int, minX float, minY float, maxX float, maxY float)
tag(poi_id int, key text, value text)


SELECT (DISTINCT(tag.key,tag.value), (poi.minlon*poi.minlat)
FROM tag,poi
WHERE tag.poi_id=tag.poi_id
GROUP BY tag.key,tag.value;
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around tag.key, tag.value. Also, remove the left parenthesis between SELECT and DISTINCT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DISTINCT is not a function and does not take parameters. It must also follow directly after the SELECT keyword. Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag.key, tag.value, (poi.minlon*poi.minlat)
FROM tag,poi
WHERE tag.poi_id=tag.poi_id
GROUP BY tag.key,tag.value;
```

DISTINCT applies to the entire tuple (row) returned, not to values in individual columns.

Comment: I was thinking that. Was wondering if DISTINCT would interfere with the multiplication results?

Comment: If duplicate values exist in every column including the result of your calculation, then the duplicated rows will be removed from the final result leaving only one occurrence of that row.

Comment: You should be able to set up a simple test to verify this. Provide two records with tag.key and tag.value with the same values and then set minlon and minlat to have values of (5, 10) for the first record and (2, 25) for the second record.